# Size for root partition, /usr partition, and /usr/local partition?

Tags: partitioning

I have an 8gb hard drive where I am installing Ubuntu. How big should each partition be?

Comment: For 8 GB I would keep everything in a single partition, the default. But then that is me. This is not a good question for this question answer site. Note, this is not a discussion forum.  See https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask for the types of question not suitable here.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have any other specific requirements, it's a good idea to go with the default.

In this case, assuming no full disk encryption, the typical setup would be to have everything in one big partition with the possible exception of a swap partition, which on a hard drive this small should be kept to a couple hundred MB at most, if you have one at all.